# ionic project for wifi-detection and connection

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to create a ionic project for wifi-network-detection. I came across some plugins like **wifiwizards,cordova plugin diagnostic to check wifi connection and also cordova plugin hotspot**. But how should I include these plugins to my *ionic project*. Should I create a *blank ionic project* to add these plugins or how should I put these plugins to my **index.html** and **app.js** file. Please someone help me with these as I'm new to these.

Sample Project:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!--ngCordova script-->
    <script src = "lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content padding = "true">
        <div class = "card">
            <div class = "item item-text-wrap">
                <h1>Network: {{network}}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "card">
            <div class = "item item-text-wrap">
                <ion-toggle ng-model = "isOnline" ng-checked = "item.checked">
                    <h1 ng-show = "isOnline">I'm into Wifi</h1>
                    <h1 ng-show = "! isOnline">I'm out off Wifi</h1>
                </ion-toggle>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js** where I included the plugin(**ngCordova**)

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $rootScope){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
       $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
       $scope.isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
       $scope.$apply();

       //listen for onloine event
       $rootscope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
       $scope.isOnline = true;
       $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

       $scope.$apply();
       })

       //listen for offline event
       $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
       console.log("got offline");
       $scope.isOnline = false;
       $scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

       $scope.$apply();
       })


    }, false);
});
```

Now how to write to check for the wifi detection and connectivity. The plugin I used is the **cordova-network-information**

Comment: Just create a new project and add these plugins as "ionic plugin add plugin_name"

Comment: are you using this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information. if not then share the plugin link

Comment: You have a tutorial. what else you need. Aren't you getting desired results with this tutorial or is there anything you can't understand

Comment: then what you need ?

Comment: don't know how to do that but I think ".getNetwork()" is giving you all the network around you. So you just need to auto connect to them.

Comment: its in your code. Read and try to understand your code even it is copied. Check this line in your code "$scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();". Now this $scope.network will have all the networks around you.

Comment: type alert($scope.network); after *$scope.network = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();* and run you code.

Comment: there must be something else in your that stop your controller being run. debug that.

Comment: @Atula, im new to all of these stuffs, I do by seeing a sample so Im not sure about what you say and can u please delete some of your comments because my window is saying to start a chat.

Comment: Or please provide me a better sample or a link which works in android

Comment: i don't any right now. But I would suggest you to go through the official readme file of the plugin.

Comment: okay, if you get something please help

Answer (score 1):

Choose a template to start from (blank, sidemenu, tabs etc). Create your new project using `ionic start [name] [templateName]` step into the folder and add the plugins you need by calling `ionic plugin add [plugin]`.
Now read the documentation for the plugins and start by implementing the examples they often show in their github repo. Then modify to your needs.